# Node.js: Why do we increment version number in package.json?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

What is the main reason for incrementing the version # in `package.json` in a normal `Node.js` project?

Comment: what do you mean?
You want that if another team member working with you, you 2 will have the same versions.

Comment: @Talg123 and why would that make a difference?

Comment: Each version can have a difference functions, most of the times things get deprecated and new things come out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version is just about semantics, to set the version characteristics scope you are working with for anyone who needs to know.

Lets say your version is like major.minor.patch (ex: 1.1.1)
You increase:
MAJOR version when you make incompatible API changes,
MINOR version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
PATCH version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

Extended information can be found [here](https://semver.org/) (as @Phix has commented)

Answer (score 2):

Normally the code would be booked into a repository like git. Several people can work on the code and when it is released into an environment for testing the version number can be changed. The release may then be referred to by the version number.

The complexity of the changes in the release should be highlighted by the way the version number is changed.

1.0.0 -> 1.0.1 Would reflect only a small change was released.
1.2.34 ->  2.0.0 Would highlight that there has been a major release.

There is no real reason to increment it if you are only learning.

Comment: @MajedBadawi [semver](https://semver.org/) has nothing to do with performance.

Answer (score 1):

It just a software development process to increment version on every significant update.

NPM normally follow semver versioning that is **Major.Minor.Patch** (i.e. 1.0.0).

1. Increment **MAJOR** version when you make incompatible API changes,
2. Increment **MINOR** version when you add functionality in a backwards compatible manner, and
3. Increment **PATCH** version when you make backwards compatible bug fixes.

Additional labels for pre-release and build metadata are available as extensions to the MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH format.